# python socketIO_client не получается подключиться к namespace

Tags: python, socket.io

Не получается подключиться к `namespace` в python socketIO_client

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO

socketIO = SocketIO('http://127.0.0.1')
# socketIO = SocketIO('http://127.0.0.1/my_chat')  # return 404

def test(*args):
    print(args)

socketIO.on('chat', test)
```

На JS сообщения приходят, на python когда добавляю `namespace` как в js - ошибка 404
Код на js:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить `namespace` таким образом:

```
socketIO.on('chat', test, path='/my_chat')
```

Или используя класс `BaseNamespace` в доках - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/socketIO-client

Comment: Спасибо, это работает, с классом не получилось разобраться